# How to sum up a range of numbers in a report, by defining the ranging using the report's multiple rows' name plus multiple columns' names?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Attached picture Cell M6 has my existing formula solution to my own question. But I'm wondering is there a better formula solution? Because it is tiring to define ACCT dimension by booking 3 formulas and adding them up. Also, in the future Term X has a new definition by not only ACCT 2 and ACCT 4, but also ACCT 6, ACCT 7, ACCT 8, I need to add more formulas to sum up. Ideally, I could define ACCT just like how I'm defining PROJECT by just using $L$2:$L$5.

Any idea will be much appreciated!!! Thank you for your time!!!

[image: Existing Formula Solution]

Comment: I haven't tried it, but for office 365 the `REDUCE` function seems like a viable alternative.

Comment: @gns100 Thank you so much!!! I mean I really could not thank you more. Working successfully!!! `=REDUCE(0, $I6:$K6, LAMBDA(Term_X,ACCT, IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF($2:$2, L$2:L$5, INDEX($1:$1048576, MATCH(ACCT, $B:$B, 0), 0))), 0) + Term_X))`

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://superuser.com/help) Answering your own question is fine, even applauded, but it has to be 'a question' followed by 'one or more answers' one of which can be accepted as 'best' by the question poster. Posting a solution like a blog just doesn't fit how SE works. the whole thing is also a little terse.

Comment: @Tetsujin, Hi Tetsujin, sorry about that! I have moved my answer out of my question zone into its answer zone. Thanks Tetsujin for this reminder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ISNUMBER(MATCH())` to test if it is in the lists:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$3:$G$7*(ISNUMBER(MATCH($B$3:$B$7,$I$6:$K$6,0)))*(ISNUMBER(MATCH($C$2:$G$2,$L$2:$L$5,0))))
```

Now it will test if the Acct and the Project are in their respective lists and return the values at the intersections or 0 where they do not intersect to the SUMPRODUCT to sum.

Comment: Solved! Thank you so much Scott!

Answer (score 1):

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYRtH.png)

Solution # 1 (I like it better) `=REDUCE(0, A5:C5, LAMBDA(X,R, X+IFERROR(SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF($G$1:$XFD$1, D$1:D$4, INDEX($G:$XFD, MATCH(R, $G:$G, 0), 0))), 0)))`
This idea was provided from @gns100, thank you gns100!

Solution # 2 `=SUMPRODUCT(($H$2:$ZZ$9999)*(ISNUMBER(MATCH($H$1:$ZZ$1,D$1:D$4,0))*(ISNUMBER(MATCH($G$2:$G$9999,$A5:$C5,0)))))`
This idea was provided from @Scott Craner, thank you Scott!

Any other solutions or ideas are much welcomed!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't followed this saga, just been aware of it. So perhaps the below has already been suggested somewhere deep in the tale. But if not:

```
=SUM( INDEX(C3:G7, MATCH(J5:K5, B3:B7, 0), MATCH(L2:L4, C2:G2, 0) ) )
```

Just `INDEX` the data in the table, find rows and columns to place in the formula's virtual table using `MATCH` on the row and column headers with the supplied list as the match values. Then `SUM` (which ignores the non-numerical entries that might exist).

Or make it nicer to change as needs grow using `LET` (which makes it look monstrous, but eases maintenance greatly:

```
=LET(MatchAccounts, J5:K5, MatchProjects, L2:L4,
      Data, C3:G7, AllAccounts, B3:B7, AllProjects, C2:G2,

      SUM( INDEX(Data, MATCH(MatchAccounts,AllAccounts,0), MATCH(MatchProjects,AllProjects,0) ) ) )
```

Now the the likeliest needed changes can be made in the first line and the next likeliest in the second line. No hunting about in the formula itself. Super-easy to add to the ranges for the rows and columns of interest.

It does not handle a blank, or any non-matching entry in those ranges very well, just giving the `#N/A` error. If such a need exists, it should be relatively easy to accommodate though.

Comment: yep, I need to back out of those new excel formulas and get back to basics. Based on another task I began thinking of using `MAKEARRAY`, then thought I nesting `FILTER`s but none of that is needed.